# Check current user is SharePoint Administrator

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, csom

Is it possible to check if the current account is a SharePoint administrator? The only way I can think of achieving this is by attempting to login to the https://tenant-admin.sharepoint.com and check if I get a 403.

I thought there might be a cleaner way of doing this? This if for SharePoint Online/Office 365

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
using (var ctx = new ClientContext(webUri))
{
    var currentUser = ctx.Web.CurrentUser;
    ctx.Load(currentUser);
    ctx.ExecuteQuery();

    Console.WriteLine(currentUser.IsSiteAdmin);
}
```

Comment: what would I use for the webUri, to use the clientcontext would I not neet to authenticate against -admin.sharepoint url which would throw a 403 erro?

Comment: use your https://<domainname>.sharepoint.com url as webUri

Comment: Thanks, that looks like it works with the testing I have done.

Comment: do you know if there is a way of doing this for SharePoint On Premise? Is there a general url I can use?

Comment: Which type of general url?

Comment: You mentioned in your previous comment I could use this url https://<domainname>.sharepoint.com for sharepoint online. Is there away to determine if a user is SharePoint admin

Answer (score 9):

REST API:

Use the below rest api to determine the current loggin user is site collection admin or not

```
https://<sharepointsiteurl>/_api/web/currentUser/issiteadmin
```

This returns the `true` or `false` value in xml format.

JS Format:
Use the below SharePoint ecmaScript to identify the current user admin status,

```
function checkUserisSiteAdmin() {
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext();
    oUser = clientContext.get_web().get_currentUser();

    clientContext.load(oUser);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
        Function.createDelegate(this, function() {
            var userInfo = '';
            userInfo +='LoginName: '+ oUser.get_loginName() +', SiteAdmin: '+ oUser.get_isSiteAdmin();            
            alert(userInfo.toString());
        }),
        Function.createDelegate(this, function(sender, args) {           
            alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
        }));
}
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(checkUserisSiteAdmin, "sp.js");
```

Answer (score 4):

In `CSOM`, you can execute the following line of code:

```
_spPageContextInfo.isSiteAdmin;
```

Example:

```
alert(_spPageContextInfo.isSiteAdmin);
```